# Does the principle of explosion prove the laws of logic are independent of the mind?

Tags: logic

A friend said that if the universe does not adhere to the laws of logic, then under principle of explosion anything is possible. Is he wrong? If not how does that work?

Comment: Title and question seems unrelated ... Seemingly, the laws of logic are independent of the (human) mind irrespective of the principle of explosion.

Comment: What does it mean that "the universe does not adhere to the laws of logic" ? That it is *inconsistent* ? Consistency is a feature of of a set of statements: is the world a set of statements ?

Comment: Interesting idea. I wonder what the "principle of explosion" is. Do you have a reference? It would help ground the question for me.

Comment: @FrankHubeny Wikipedia...

Comment: @MichaelK Thanks. The question makes sense now. The principle of explosion is that one can infer anything from a contradiction.  Now I wonder, even if the universe does not adhere to the laws of logic, does that mean it is totally random?

Comment: Your friend asserts principle of explosion is true: but that's your friend who asserts that, therefore, it is dependent on mind. I would not say it somehow proves laws of logic are mind-independent and even more believe laws of reality cannot be deduced from laws of logic (truth is dependent on context).

Comment: Shouldn't that be that if the universe **does** adhere to the laws of logic then under the principle of explosion, anything is possible?  The principle is itself one of the laws of logic.  If the outside world follows **different** rules than classical logic, ones that do not include this axiom, only **then** is there any good reason why even though paradoxes exist, not everything is possible.

Comment: How can a law of logic prove something about laws of logic? That would be circular, wouldn't it? And if the universe does *not* adhere to the laws of logic then why are we applying the law of explosion to it? That is plainly incoherent. Not to mention that laws of logic apply to reasoning in the first place, not to the universe. It's not even that this is wrong, it makes no sense at all.

Comment: Graham Priest defends true contradictions on the grounds that they need not be explosive. I do not believe he is correct to suggest there are any or to say they are not explosive, but his argument is relevant and you may like it.

Answer (score 1):

https://xkcd.com/704/ Analogise from this, other information flows that are counter-causal, or 'counter-logical'. Fundamentally, causality and logic are ways of grouping experiences to make sense of them. If someone has an alternate way of doing that which helps them navigate infornation more effectively, that is the new causality & logic.

The question becomes, can we navigate information without trying to make sense of it? Whether or not we can, reflects not at all on the infornation, which flows how physics says

Answer (score 0):

I think your conclusion may fundamentally be based on a confusion between "*epistemic uncertainty*" and "*ontological uncertainty*", as very briefly distinguished on the bottom paragraph of page 41 of
*Hilbert Space and Quantum Logic*
     https://books.google.com/books?id=dJfbBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA41

The world not being logical doesn't mean that it's not "something-or-other", which may or may not constrain (in some illogical way) the collection of "possible worlds". What it does mean is that
     **>>your state of knowledge about that world<<**
is probably severely limited, *e.g.*, mathematical physics no longer "works". In particular, regarding your question, physics may not be able to distinguish "possible worlds" from impossible ones. But just because you can't identify such "impossible worlds", doesn't mean they don't exist. Just means the world's a complete (or maybe only partial) mystery to you.

So, in brief, I think you're maybe confusing the state of the world (ontological) with your state of knowledge about the world (epistemic). An "illogical world" may have a more profound effect on your state of knowledge about that world than it has on that world itself.

Answer (score -1):

## Contradictions only break logic, not reality

Just in the same way that this is not a pipe...

[image]

...but just a **description** of a pipe, logic is merely used to describe and deduce reality and how it works. Logic is not reality, and it does not **control** how reality works. We only **assume** the universe behaves in a manner that is consistent with logic. But logic does not dictate reality.

If reality then turns to — in one instance — behave in a manner that is inconsistent with logic, it only proves that logic is not enough to describe the universe, **or** — even more likely — that we lack the information that is needed to use logic to describe reality properly. If reality behaves in a manner that is contradictory to logic, only logic is broken, not reality. Reality still does its own thing... it is just that now you have made us humans a whole lot more nervous (or excited), because now we have a lesser understanding of it.

### Example

Suppose we one day find a pocket of space where gravity is reversed. This is **completely** contradictory to logic and the laws of physics as we know them.

Does that mean that unicorns can exist?

Well... no, and yes. Unicorns can exist, but that is no different from how the situation is today. That pocket of reversed gravity does not speak for or against the existence of unicorns.

So is reality **separate** from the laws of logic? Yes, it is. There is nothing that **dictates** that reality must adhere to logic. We only know that it has done so.

...so far.